# Get Github repositories owners in an Organization

Tags: github, graphql

I'm trying to get a list of Admin inside a repository in an organization,

couldn't find a away to get it working, always returning me Organization name instead of Administrator name of the repository

```
query Github {
  organization(login: "platform-test") {
    repositories(first: 100,after:"Y3Vyc29ysd654OAAKz-A==") {
      nodes {
        nameWithOwner
     owner{
      login
      id
      __typename
      url
     }
      
      }
      pageInfo {
        endCursor
        hasNextPage
      }
      totalCount
    }
  }
}
```

Will return this snap of result :

```
  "data": {
    "organization": {
      "repositories": {
        "nodes": [
          {
            "nameWithOwner": "Platform-test/afapi-aps-bigfix",
            "owner": {
              "login": "Platform-test",
              "id": "MDEyOk9yZ2FuaXphdGlvbjc2NjA=",
              "__typename": "Organization",
              "url": "https://github.dxc.com/Platform-test"
            }
          },
          {
            "nameWithOwner": "Platform-test/CVA-operation-k8s-pre",
            "owner": {
              "login": "Platform-test",
              "id": "MDEyOk9yZ2FuaXphdGlvbjc2NjA=",
              "__typename": "Organization",
              "url": "https://github.dxc.com/Platform-test"
            }
          },....
```

Couldn't find a way to get the list of administrators of a repository inside an Org

Answer (score 0):

I user this query to retrieve the Admins

```
{
organization(login: "Coorp") {
    repositories(first: 100, after: null) {
        nodes {
            id
            nameWithOwner
            description
            url
            collaborators(first: 20, after: null) {
                edges {
                    permission
                    node {
                        id
                        name
                        email
                    }
                }
                pageInfo {
                    hasNextPage
                    endCursor
                }
            }
        }
        pageInfo {
            hasNextPage
            endCursor
        }
    }
}
```

}